# How do I correctly create an offset between div's

Tags: html, css, width, margin

At the moment I do this:

```
.column-33 {
    width: 32%;
    float:left;
}
```

I want to have the width changed to 33.33% but my item is styled like this:

```
.news-collection-item {
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

So what happens is there will only be 2 items in line when the width is set to 33.33%. What would be the correct way to handle with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixels and percents aren't compatible this way. Use one of them, in this case percentages.

```
.column-33 {width: 32%; float: left;}
.column-33 + .column-33 {margin-left: 2%;} /* set to 2nd and 3rd col left margin */
/* OR .column-33:nth-child(3n+2), .column-33:nth-child(3n) {} if you have more than 3 columns  */
```

Comment: I changed things up a little and got this now: .column-33 {
    width: 31%;
    margin: 0% 1%;
    float: left;
} Which works.

Comment: @Script99: and you know gap before 1st and after the 3rd element? I made you gaps only around the middle one :-)

Comment: The layout I need to work with is 10px-320px-10px etc.. so thats why :)

Comment: @Script99: okay, then it simple, width you can use `31.333%`

Answer (score 0):

When you set a width, the margin will additionate.

In your exemple your column width is 33.33% + 10px (5px for each side).
But 1% is variable (1px if the conainer width is 100px, but 3px if the container width is 300px) and 5px wiil always be 5%.

So you need mix relative and absolute value, don't worry, when i need to do this, i do something like this :

```
<div class='column-33'>
  <div class='inner'>
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class='column-33'>
  <div class='inner'>
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class='column-33'>
  <div class='inner'>
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS :

```
.column-33 {
  width: 32%;
  float:left;
}
.column-33 .inner{
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just overwrite the margin setting in .column-33, setting that to 0. I believe that you are tying to display 3 divs equally, side by side, on the page. The margin is causing the 3rd div to be forced onto the second line. Removing it/redefining the classes should help.

Answer (score 0):

I have to contradict panther's answer.

Pixel and percent values can in fact be used together with the [`calc()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#calc-notation) CSS function, which is also [supported by most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

So you can write it as `width: calc(33% - 2px)`, modulo vendor prefixes.